# How to select start and end date in seconds in a chosen column in df

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I need to select from the column in df start time 2023-12-18 06:00:00 to end time 2023-12-19.
I have the next dataset:

```
   CreatedUtc               ID
0     2023-12-18 05:20:00  122845
1     2023-12-18 06:00:00  140252
2     2023-12-18 06:15:00  156053
5     2023-12-18 08:00:00  412487
6     2023-12-19 03:00:00  973645
7     2023-12-19 18:50:00  159745
```

Here what I’ve done, but in the output I got 0 rows.

```
start = df["CreatedUtc"] >= "2023-12-18 06:00:00"
end = df["CreatedUtc"] <= "2023-12-19 06:00:00"
between_two_dates = start & end
df.loc[between_two_dates]
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. Please provide some sample data that demonstrates the problem. Read [ask] and [mre] and [edit] your question.

Comment: @Nick you are right, just edited the question

Comment: What is the dtype of `df["CreatedUtc"]`?

Comment: It showed me that it's an object

Comment: I found the solution, have changed the dtype, thank you for help

Comment: No worries - I'm glad you figured it  out.